# How can I open the Steam console from the flatpak version of Steam?

Tags: steam, linux

In Linux (Fedora Silverblue) I have attempted to open the Steam console using a terminal with the command "steam -console", which [this steam community thread suggests](https://steamcommunity.com/app/221410/discussions/0/1640915206440178749/), but that did not work. How can I open the Steam console from the flatpak version of Steam?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You run flatpak apps by prepending your command with `flatpak run`, like so:

```
flatpak run com.valvesoftware.Steam "steam://open/console"
```